# How can set optional parameter in method

Tags: c#, typescript

I want to set an object as an optional parameter;

```
public async hearted(p, typeID, refID, [Optional] stud: Student) {  return ;}
```

how to set `[Optional] stud: Student`.

Comment: use `= null` after parmeter

Comment: Following what @viveknuna said, keep in mind that optional parameters can only come last.

Comment: @Christopher thank you for advice pls check the question I want to set the optional parameter with object how can i set?

Comment: Student sounds like a pretty complex thing, that would require a ton of fields to be set. Usually the default should be setting it to Null, so code can quickly check for it's absence.